# Python3.7: RegEx for string between strings on multiple lines?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to find `30,850` in:

```
  <div class='user-information__achievements-heading' data-test-points-title>
    Points
    </div>
    <div class='user-information__achievements-data' data-test-points-count>
    30,850
    </div>
    </div>
```

with:

```
^(?!<div class='user-information__achievements-data' data-test-points-count>
|<.div>)(.*)$
```

(returns nothing)

How come `^(?!START\-OF\-FIELDS|END\-OF\-FIELDS)(.*)$` does work for:

```
START-OF-FIELDS
<div>
Line A
END-OF-FIELDS
```

(returns `<div>`)?

Comment: I do hope you're not trying to [parse HTML with regex...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Better to use `BeautifulSoup` to parse html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can search text by bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tx = """
  <div class='user-information__achievements-heading' data-test-points-title>
    Points
    </div>
    <div class='user-information__achievements-data' data-test-points-count>
    30,850
    </div>
    </div>
"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(tx,"lxml")
result = bs.find("div",{"class":"user-information__achievements-data"}).text
print(result.strip()) # 30,850
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides I totally agree to [never parse HTML with re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) (and it's really fun to read, btw) if you only have this piece of text and need a quick `re.search`, a simple `r'\d+,\d+'` would do...:

```
import re

s = '''<div class='user-information__achievements-heading' data-test-points-title>
    Points
    </div>
    <div class='user-information__achievements-data' data-test-points-count>
    30,850
    </div>
    </div>'''

re.search(r'\d+,\d+', s)
<re.Match object; span=(179, 185), match='30,850'>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex just do:

```
i="    <div class='user-information__achievements-data' data-test-points-count>"
print(s.splitlines()[s.splitlines().index(i)+1].lstrip())
```

Output:

```
30,850
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `re.DOTALL` because by default `.` doesn't match newlines and line brakes.

```
re.compile(YOUR_REGEX, flags=re.S)
```

You can also prepend your regex with `(?s)` for the same effect.